# Python Common Power of Three

Tags: python, math

I am trying to build a python program that will give me the highest power of any two numbers that is the highest power of 3
If I enter 3 and 6 the answer should be 3

This is returning null

```
def common_power_of_three(a,b):
    def check_power_of3(n):
        while n % 3 ==0:
           n/=3
           return n ==1
           
           
def all_comm_div(a,b):
    comm_div = []
    for i in range(1, min(a,b) +1):
        if a%1 ==b % i==0:
            comm_div.append(i)
            return comm_div
            
def main():
    a=int(input("1st "))
    b=int(input("2st "))
    divs = all_comm_div(a,b)
    for x in reversed(divs):
        if check_power_of3(x) == True:
            print(x)
            break
```

Comment: Your function *common_power_of_three()* (if you ever call it) will always return None. The code shown is not runnable. Also, you might want to give some more example of input and expected output. As it is, the description doesn't make much sense

Comment: ok my example was 3 and 6

Comment: If you are allowed to use the `math` module, you can check if a number `n` is power of `3`  with `int(pow(3, math.log(n, 3))) == int(pow(3, int(math.log(n, 3))))`.

Comment: There aren't many powers of three you can store in a 64 bit integer so you could just use a look-up table for speed.

Comment: Are you just trying to determine, given 2 numbers, which of them is divisible by 3 more than the other? If not, please describe more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: im trying to program something that gives me the greatest power of 3 which divides two integers. So the greates power of 3 in (6 and 24) is 3

Answer (score 2):

`d = math.gcd(a, b)` will give you the GCD of `a` and `b` as `d`. Then simply find out the highest power of 3 in d. You want to use the `//`operator, not the `/` operator. `/` is for floating point division.

```py
import math
def highest_power_of_3(a:int, b:int):
    d = math.gcd(a, b)
    power = 0
    while d % 3 == 0:
        power += 1
        d //= 3
    return power
```